# Gesture recognizer and AndEngine (Android)

Tags: android, view, andengine, gesture

In the game I'm developing I need this function: being able to draw on the screen and to establish if the drawing is a determined shape (let's say a rectangle, triangle or whatever).

So I wanted to use gestures, which are the easier way to do that; with the gesture builder I made a few shapes and I use them as models. The thing is, I can't make it work with the AndEngine.

I need the GestureOverlayView, which is basically the drawing board, to be placed ON TOP of the scene of the game, so that I can see the scene itself with all the entities attached and I can also draw gesture.

Right now what I tried didn't work, either the AndEngine stuff is shown on screen or the GestureOverlayView is, not both.

I'm new both with android developing and the AndEngine, so I'm kinda stuck here... do you have any ideas on how could I make it work? I looked everywhere but I can't find anything useful...

I'll leave the code of the gesture part below just for example, it won't really work obviously if you don't have any pre-made gestures in the path res/raw of the project:

```
public class ProvaGesture extends Activity implements GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener        
{

     private GestureLibrary gestureLib;

     public  GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView;


     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);

          gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);

          gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);

          if (!gestureLib.load())
          {
                finish();
          }

           setContentView(gestureOverlayView);
      }


     public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture)
     {
           ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLib.recognize(gesture);

           for (Prediction prediction : predictions) 
           {
                 if (prediction.score > 1.0) 
                 {
                        Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
           }
     }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't see AndEngine part in your demo code. Your `ProvaGesture` activity should be extended from AndEgine's `SimpleBaseGameActivity` or `BaseGameActivity` then implements `IOnSceneTouchListener`.

Base on your idea, I guessed that you try to create a separated overlay view which handles only the gesture, so you must consider:

- You have only **one activity running at a time** in android.
- If you want to create an **User-defined view** overlaping the AndEgine's surface view, you should see Andengine's example: `XMLLayoutExample`.

**The solution may be** [suggested]:

```
public class OverlapLayoutExample extends SimpleLayoutGameActivity {
@Override
protected int getLayoutID() {
    //your layout id (xml file in layout folder)
    return R.layout.overlaplayout;
}

@Override
protected int getRenderSurfaceViewID() 
{
    //overlaplayout will contain a SurfaceView with following ID
    //this surface is where you render Andgine
    return R.id.overlaplayout_rendersurfaceview;
}
}
```

Don't forget to create your own layout: `overlaplayout` containing `surfaceView` and `OverlayView`

Comment: Sorry, I completly forgot that I wrote here! A few days after writing here I discovered the example you mentioned and I almost managed to do what I wanted; then I've got the final tip I needed in the AndEngine forum: andengine.org/forums/post38876.html#p38876

Comment: Not it detects gestures, but it turned out that I've got another problem now. I wanted to not use the gesture stroke and instead make the drawing using the AndEngine (creating Line objects), but only part of the input is registered; I mean that it draws part of the gesture and then stops, like it was an ACTION_UP event and not a ACTION_MOVE; So, I was thinking about using the gesture normal stroke, but since the AndEngine is on top of the GestureOverlayView, the stroke is invisible... Is there a way to make it visible?

Comment: Actually nevermind, I managed to disable the gesture stroke and it's all ok now!